# Upload files to S3 from form

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask

I'm new with s3 and trying to upload some files but the I'm getting `The system cannot find the file specified: <hashed_file_name>.jpg` I understand the issue. When the file is saved at the root, everything is fine. But I don't want to save the file. I want to upload it directly after the `action` at the `form`.

```
def upload_to_s3(file_to_upload, s3_upload_folder):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
                    aws_access_key_id=app.config['ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                    aws_secret_access_key=app.config['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])

    s3.meta.client.upload_file(file_to_upload, app.config['BUCKET_NAME'], s3_upload_folder)


def _user_img_folder(form, file_name):
    username = session['name']
    vacation_name = slugify(form.test_name.data)
    directory = os.path.join(username, test_name)
    directory = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, directory)
    return directory + '/' + file_name


@app.route('/post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    if _is_image():
        uploaded_images = request.files.getlist('photo')
        for image in uploaded_images:
            processed_image_name = _hash_image_name(image) # Returns hashed filename with extension
            directory = _user_img_folder(form, processed_image_name)
            upload_to_s3(str(processed_image_name), str(directory))
    return render_template('test.html', form=form, error=error)
```

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT 1:**

{# Heavily edited #}

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form class="logVacation" enctype=multipart/form-data role="form" method="post" action="/post">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.vacation_name(placeholder="Name Your Vacation")}}
        <br>
        {{ form.location(placeholder="Where was it?") }}
        <br>
        {{ form.with_who(placeholder='Who was with you') }}
        <br><br>
        {{ form.description(placeholder="Tell us about your vacation... or not.") }}<br>
        {{ form.when(class="datepicker", placeholder="when?") }}
        <br><br>
        {{ form.photo(multiple="multiple") }}
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="upload" type="submit">Done</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: change to `methods=['POST']`

Comment: @hjpotter92 actually it's there but forgot to type I guess.

Comment: Can you please post the `<form>` you have?

Comment: @hjpotter92 posted^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

I've changed the

```
s3.meta.client.upload_file(file_to_upload, app.config['BUCKET_NAME'], s3_upload_folder)
```

to:

```
s3.Object(app.config['BUCKET_NAME'], s3_upload_folder).put(Body=image)
```

so the trick is, you must either have the file on disk and provide `filepath` with `file_to_upload` OR provide the file itself as I demonstrated in this answer.